# check if image exists or not and build string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a string depending on an image whether it exists or not, if it exists then build an image tag if it doesn't then create an empty div tag with a class .no-image how can I accomplish this - could some give me some help

```
    $('#search_movies').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "http://localhost:8000/admin/tmdb/search",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        type: 'POST',
        results: function (data, page) {
            console.log(data);
            return { results: data.d };
        },
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            // page: params.page
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
          // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
          // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
          // scrolling can be used
          //params.page = params.page || 1;

          console.log(data)
          return {
            results: data.items,
            // pagination: {
            //   more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
            // }
          };
        },
        cache: false
      },
      escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
      templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    });


function formatRepo(repo) {
    if (repo.loading) return repo.text;


    var markup = '<div data-id="' + repo.id + '" class="option clearfix">';
        markup += '<div class="option-image"><img alt="" src="' + repo.image + '"></div>';
        markup += '<div class="option-content">';
            markup += '<h4>' + repo.title + '</h4>';
            markup += '<h4>' + repo.release_date + '</h4>';
            markup += '<h4>' + repo.popularity + '</h4>';
        markup += '</div>';
    markup += '</div>';


    return markup;
}


function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
    return repo.title || repo.text;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine if `url` points to a valid path to image file?

Comment: yes that's right the code checks but doesn't build the string

Comment: what code sets repo.loading to true? and sets repo.text

Comment: `load` event of `<img>` element is asynchronous. You could alternatively use `$.ajax()` `HEAD` request.

Comment: thats select2 data don't worry about that that's not important

Comment: could you give me an example, I tried that before and it gave me an error for X-CSRF-TOKEN in the header

Comment: @ONYX Have not tried `select2`. Not sure what you are trying to achieve other than checking if `url` is path to valid resource? You could also use `Promise` to resolve `markup` value within `load` event, chain `.then()` to perform task with `markup` value.

Comment: that's all I need to do to validate an image if exists but not working I tried doing a get $.get(repo.image).done(function() {}).fail(function() {}); can't seem to build that string

Comment: if repo.loading is false, your function `formatRepo` will return `''` - because as mentioned earlier, the load event of img is asynchronous

Comment: that's just return a loading text status after there is data returned then it processes the repo function to format the data

Comment: yes, which will be `''` - is that what you expect?

Comment: so then after repo.loading is false then it formats the repo function

Comment: I can procerss images and get images to load no worries but when I want to check that an image exists I run into problems

Comment: this code attempts to return HTML with an image tag in it if the image exists ... however, it wont, because the function will **always return** `''` - a blank string ... the string in the `var markup` will never be anything but `''` on return from that function - making this function do absolutely nothing but attempt to download and ignore an image ... outside of this function, the existence of the image remains unknown

Comment: At the moment that's what it's doing I know that

Comment: I don't know how to build the string can you help do that

Comment: yes ... and there's no way for it to return anything else ... it can not return any indicator that the image exists - because image onload is asynchronouos

Comment: you need to know how to use asynchronous code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `formatRepo` return the markup, make it pass the markup to a callback function like.

```
function formatRepo(repo, markupCallback) {
     function imageExists(url, callback) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() { callback(true); };
        img.onerror = function() { callback(false); };
        img.src = url;
    }

    imageExists(repo.image, function(exists) {
        var markup = '';
        if(exists) {
            markup += '<img src="' + repo.image + '">'; 
        } else {
            markup += '<div class="no-image"></div>';
        }
        // pass markup to markupCallback
        markupCallback(markup);
    });
}

// and then use it like
formatRepo(myRepo, function(markup){
    // use markup here
});
```

Comment: @ONYX seems impossible to me since it all get passed to `select2` which I assume it's a library function and you can't modify it to adapt for the asynchronous nature of `formatRepo`.